# Seding data to display as a columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1

In a given table; I am querying to display certain columns as below

```
select an.animals_key,           
       an.anim_name,
       an.sex,
       an.date_of_birth,
       tt.trait_key,            
       --case when tt.trait_key = 152 then 'Left Eye Pigment'
            --when tt.trait_key = 153 then 'Right Eye Pigment' end as trait_key,
       tt.trait_value,
       tt.observation_date

 from animals an
 join traits tt on tt.soc_code = an.soc_code and tt.animals_key = an.animals_key and tt.trait_key in (152,153)
 where an.soc_code = 'AUHF' limit 10
```

This query produced me the following data.

[image]

Is there any way, i can put 152 as one column and 153 into one column so that I can put all trait values in those columns

Comment: Do trait values differ at all? It looks like it's `100` all the way.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns is always predefined (152, 153 in your case) you can do  conditional aggregation

```sql
select an.animals_key, an.anim_name, an.sex, an.date_of_birth, tt.observation_date
       min(case when tt.trait_key = 152 then tt.trait_value end) "152",
       min(case when tt.trait_key = 153 then tt.trait_value end) "153"
  from animals an join traits tt 
    on tt.soc_code = an.soc_code 
   and tt.animals_key = an.animals_key
   and tt.trait_key in (152, 153)
 where an.soc_code = 'AUHF'
 group by an.animals_key, an.anim_name, an.sex, an.date_of_birth, tt.observation_date
```